# Как для каждой новой странице сделать отдельный local storage?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Мой код:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
       $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
x=$('.plane').position();
        x1=x.left;
        y1=x.top;
 localStorage.setItem('leftplane',x1);
 localStorage.setItem('topplane',y1);       

      }
    });
 $('.plane').css('top',localStorage.getItem('topplane')+'px');
$('.plane').css('left',localStorage.getItem('leftplane')+'px');
$('#rese').click(function(){
  localStorage.removeItem('leftplane');
  localStorage.removeItem('topplane');
   $('.plane').css('top','0px');
     $('.plane').css('left','0px');               
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы для каждого нового файла скрипт создавал новый local storage с другим названием?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте идентификатор страницы к ключам

```
// для первой страницы
attachDraggable("home");

// для второй страницы
attachDraggable("contacts");

function attachDraggable(id) {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
         drop: function( event, ui ) {
             var x = $('.plane').position();
             localStorage.setItem(id + '__leftplane', x1 = x.left);
             localStorage.setItem(id + '__topplane', y1 = x.top);       
        }
    });
    $('.plane').css('top', localStorage.getItem(id + '__topplane') + 'px');
    $('.plane').css('left', localStorage.getItem(id + '__leftplane') + 'px');
    $('#rese').click(function(){
        localStorage.removeItem(id + '__leftplane');
        localStorage.removeItem(id +   '__topplane');
        $('.plane').css('top' ,'0px');
        $('.plane').css('left', '0px');               
    });
}
```

как то так..